# Facebook graph api public information

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

using facebook graph api I can retrieve public information , for example, using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post&access_token=xxxxx
```

I can pull public posts.
I would like to restrict the public posts output - which contains status messages, links and photos . The only type of post I actually need is status messages.
Is there any way to restrict the searching?

Any suggestion would be helpful,

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Find out if the information you seek is avaible via FQL instead. If it is, specify only the fields that you want back.

Comment: It's not available via FQL , what any other option do I have ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think that it's possible to filter the results the way you want to.